# Combine multiple xlsx File in single Xlsx File

Tags: python, openpyxl, xlsxwriter

I have multiple xlsx File which contain two worksheet(data,graph). I have created graph using xlsxwriter in graph worksheet and write data in data worksheet. So I need to combine all graph worksheet into single xlsx File. So My question is:

openpyxl : In openpyxl module, we can load another workbook and modify the value.is there anyway to append new worksheet of another File. For Example.
I have two xlsx data.xlsx(graph worksheet) and data_1.xlsx(graph worksheet)
So Final xlsx (graph worksheet and graph_1 worksheet)

xlsxwriter : As of my understanding, we can not modify existing xlsx File. Do we any update into this module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might consider using `xlrd` and `xlwt` as show in one of the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15793349/how-to-concatenate-three-excels-files-xlsx-using-python).

Answer (score 0):

In answer to the last part of the question:

> xlsxwriter : As of my understanding, we can not modify existing xlsx File. Do we any update into this module.

That is correct. XlsxWriter only writes new files. It cannot be used to modify existing files. Rewriting files is not a planned feature.