# Unmerge every cell in an Excel worksheet using openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl

Is there a way to unmerge every cell in an Excel worksheet using openpyxl.  There isn't a guarentee that every or any cell is merged, but basically I want to unmerge cells if they exist in a worksheet.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can iterate through the worksheet's `merged_cells` attribute and use each one as an argument to `unmerge_cells()`. `unmerge_cells()` either takes the starting and ending rows and columns, or a range string, but the latter is easier to use by converting the value(s) from `merged_cells` to a `str`.

As an example:

```
>>> ws.merged_cells
<MultiCellRange [A2:A4 A8:D11]>

for merge in list(ws.merged_cells):
    ws.unmerge_cells(range_string=str(merge))

>>> ws.merged_cells
<MultiCellRange []>
```

(`ws.merged_cells` doesn't seem to like being iterated while you're unmerging, so `list()` avoids any issues)

Comment: Your code generates an KeyError in file \worksheet\worksheet.py:630. ws.merged_cells. ws.merged_cells.ranges is a list of all ranges!