# Python Excel copy cell style from one to another openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, formatting, openpyxl

I am struggling with the following using openpyxl version 3.0.7
I want to copy the style of one cell to another. That means, background colour, font,  etc.
However, I don't know how I can do that.

My initial idea was basically to do
`sheet["E1"].font = sheet["D1"].font`.

That bit shoots out `TypeError: unhashable type: 'StyleProxy'`.
Using just `.style` doesn't really do all that much so it's not suitable.

I found a few solutions online like [the one from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23332259/copy-cell-style-openpyxl). However, I don't know how I can apply it to my specific needs seeing as I struggle to even transfer the font from one cell to another.

Comment: I'd suggest taking the solution out of the edited question and making your own answer, then accepting it, so the question shows up in searches as answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shortly after typing this out, I found the solution.

```
from copy import copy
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('C:\\path...\\')
sheet = wb["Name of the worksheet"]

sheet["E1"].font = copy(sheet["D1"].font)
sheet["E1"].border = copy(sheet["D1"].border)
sheet["E1"].fill = copy(sheet["D1"].fill)
sheet["E1"].number_format = copy(sheet["D1"].number_format)
sheet["E1"].protection = copy(sheet["D1"].protection)
sheet["E1"].alignment = copy(sheet["D1"].alignment)
```

The only thing left to do would be to do this in a loop. That would be achievable by doing something like

```
for i in range(....): 
    sheet["E" + str(i)].font= copy(sheet["D" +str(i)].font) 
    etc.
```