# Append data to existing sheet and save it somewhere else\new name using Python

Tags: python, excel, pandas

There's this code I got from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38074678/append-existing-excel-sheet-with-new-dataframe-using-python-pandas), I'm able to solve what I need using it.
The only problem I've got is that it overwrites the original file, but in my case I must save it as a new file in another directory, with a new name.

Can someone help me tweak this code? I've tried adding an 'file_output' argument to the original formula (append_df_to_excel) but I was unable to do it properly.

Can someone help me tweak this original code?
Thank you!

````
from copy import copy
from typing import Union, Optional
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter


def copy_excel_cell_range(
      src_ws: openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.Worksheet,
      min_row: int = None,
      max_row: int = None,
      min_col: int = None,
      max_col: int = None,
      tgt_ws: openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.Worksheet = None,
      tgt_min_row: int = 1,
      tgt_min_col: int = 1,
      with_style: bool = True
) -> openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.Worksheet:
  """
  copies all cells from the source worksheet [src_ws] starting from [min_row] row
  and [min_col] column up to [max_row] row and [max_col] column
  to target worksheet [tgt_ws] starting from [tgt_min_row] row
  and [tgt_min_col] column.

  @param src_ws:  source worksheet
  @param min_row: smallest row index in the source worksheet (1-based index)
  @param max_row: largest row index in the source worksheet (1-based index)
  @param min_col: smallest column index in the source worksheet (1-based index)
  @param max_col: largest column index in the source worksheet (1-based index)
  @param tgt_ws:  target worksheet.
                  If None, then the copy will be done to the same (source) worksheet.
  @param tgt_min_row: target row index (1-based index)
  @param tgt_min_col: target column index (1-based index)
  @param with_style:  whether to copy cell style. Default: True

  @return: target worksheet object
  """
  if tgt_ws is None:
      tgt_ws = src_ws

  # https://stackoverflow.com/a/34838233/5741205
  for row in src_ws.iter_rows(min_row=min_row, max_row=max_row,
                              min_col=min_col, max_col=max_col):
      for cell in row:
          tgt_cell = tgt_ws.cell(
              row=cell.row + tgt_min_row - 1,
              column=cell.col_idx + tgt_min_col - 1,
              value=cell.value
          )
          if with_style and cell.has_style:
              # tgt_cell._style = copy(cell._style)
              tgt_cell.font = copy(cell.font)
              tgt_cell.border = copy(cell.border)
              tgt_cell.fill = copy(cell.fill)
              tgt_cell.number_format = copy(cell.number_format)
              tgt_cell.protection = copy(cell.protection)
              tgt_cell.alignment = copy(cell.alignment)
  return tgt_ws


def append_df_to_excel(
      filename: Union[str, Path],
      df: pd.DataFrame,
      sheet_name: str = 'Sheet1',
      startrow: Optional[int] = None,
      max_col_width: int = 30,
      autofilter: bool = False,
      fmt_int: str = "#,##0",
      fmt_float: str = "#,##0.00",
      fmt_date: str = "yyyy-mm-dd",
      fmt_datetime: str = "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm",
      truncate_sheet: bool = False,
      storage_options: Optional[dict] = None,
      **to_excel_kwargs
) -> None:
  """
  Append a DataFrame [df] to existing Excel file [filename]
  into [sheet_name] Sheet.
  If [filename] doesn't exist, then this function will create it.

  @param filename: File path or existing ExcelWriter
                   (Example: '/path/to/file.xlsx')
  @param df: DataFrame to save to workbook
  @param sheet_name: Name of sheet which will contain DataFrame.
                     (default: 'Sheet1')
  @param startrow: upper left cell row to dump data frame.
                   Per default (startrow=None) calculate the last row
                   in the existing DF and write to the next row...
  @param max_col_width: maximum column width in Excel. Default: 40
  @param autofilter: boolean - whether add Excel autofilter or not. Default: False
  @param fmt_int: Excel format for integer numbers
  @param fmt_float: Excel format for float numbers
  @param fmt_date: Excel format for dates
  @param fmt_datetime: Excel format for datetime's
  @param truncate_sheet: truncate (remove and recreate) [sheet_name]
                         before writing DataFrame to Excel file
  @param storage_options: dict, optional
      Extra options that make sense for a particular storage connection, e.g. host, port,
      username, password, etc., if using a URL that will be parsed by fsspec, e.g.,
      starting “s3://”, “gcs://”.
  @param to_excel_kwargs: arguments which will be passed to `DataFrame.to_excel()`
                          [can be a dictionary]
  @return: None

  Usage examples:

  >>> append_df_to_excel('/tmp/test.xlsx', df, autofilter=True,
                         freeze_panes=(1,0))

  >>> append_df_to_excel('/tmp/test.xlsx', df, header=None, index=False)

  >>> append_df_to_excel('/tmp/test.xlsx', df, sheet_name='Sheet2',
                         index=False)

  >>> append_df_to_excel('/tmp/test.xlsx', df, sheet_name='Sheet2',
                         index=False, startrow=25)

  >>> append_df_to_excel('/tmp/test.xlsx', df, index=False,
                         fmt_datetime="dd.mm.yyyy hh:mm")

  (c) [MaxU](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5741205/maxu?tab=profile)
  """
  def set_column_format(ws, column_letter, fmt):
      for cell in ws[column_letter]:
          cell.number_format = fmt
  filename = Path(filename)
  file_exists = filename.is_file()
  # process parameters
  # calculate first column number
  # if the DF will be written using `index=True`, then `first_col = 2`, else `first_col = 1`
  first_col = int(to_excel_kwargs.get("index", True)) + 1
  # ignore [engine] parameter if it was passed
  if 'engine' in to_excel_kwargs:
      to_excel_kwargs.pop('engine')
  # save content of existing sheets
  if file_exists:
      wb = load_workbook(filename)
      sheet_names = wb.sheetnames
      sheet_exists = sheet_name in sheet_names
      sheets = {ws.title: ws for ws in wb.worksheets}

  with pd.ExcelWriter(
      filename.with_suffix(".xlsx"),
      engine="openpyxl",
      mode="a" if file_exists else "w",
      if_sheet_exists="new" if file_exists else None,
      date_format=fmt_date,
      datetime_format=fmt_datetime,
      storage_options=storage_options
  ) as writer:
      if file_exists:
          # try to open an existing workbook
          writer.book = wb
          # get the last row in the existing Excel sheet
          # if it was not specified explicitly
          if startrow is None and sheet_name in writer.book.sheetnames:
              startrow = writer.book[sheet_name].max_row
          # truncate sheet
          if truncate_sheet and sheet_name in writer.book.sheetnames:
              # index of [sheet_name] sheet
              idx = writer.book.sheetnames.index(sheet_name)
              # remove [sheet_name]
              writer.book.remove(writer.book.worksheets[idx])
              # create an empty sheet [sheet_name] using old index
              writer.book.create_sheet(sheet_name, idx)
          # copy existing sheets
          writer.sheets = sheets
      else:
          # file doesn't exist, we are creating a new one
          startrow = 0

      # write out the DataFrame to an ExcelWriter
      df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet_name, **to_excel_kwargs)
      worksheet = writer.sheets[sheet_name]

      if autofilter:
          worksheet.auto_filter.ref = worksheet.dimensions

      for xl_col_no, dtyp in enumerate(df.dtypes, first_col):
          col_no = xl_col_no - first_col
          width = max(df.iloc[:, col_no].astype(str).str.len().max(),
                      len(df.columns[col_no]) + 6)
          width = min(max_col_width, width)
          column_letter = get_column_letter(xl_col_no)
          worksheet.column_dimensions[column_letter].width = width
          if np.issubdtype(dtyp, np.integer):
              set_column_format(worksheet, column_letter, fmt_int)
          if np.issubdtype(dtyp, np.floating):
              set_column_format(worksheet, column_letter, fmt_float)

  if file_exists and sheet_exists:
      # move (append) rows from new worksheet to the `sheet_name` worksheet
      wb = load_workbook(filename)
      # retrieve generated worksheet name
      new_sheet_name = set(wb.sheetnames) - set(sheet_names)
      if new_sheet_name:
          new_sheet_name = list(new_sheet_name)[0]
      # copy rows written by `df.to_excel(...)` to
      copy_excel_cell_range(
          src_ws=wb[new_sheet_name],
          tgt_ws=wb[sheet_name],
          tgt_min_row=startrow + 1,
          with_style=True
      )
      # remove new (generated by Pandas) worksheet
      del wb[new_sheet_name]
      wb.save(filename)
      wb.close()
    
# Create a sample dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'foo': ["loo", "woo", "goo"],
                        'bar': [22, 15, 7],
                        })
    
# EDIT YOUR PATH FOR THE EXPORT 
filename = r"D:\Book2.xlsx"   
    
      
append_df_to_excel(filename, df, index=False, startrow=0) # Basic Export of df in default sheet (Sheet1)```
````

Answer (score 0):

In your code you use
wb.save(filename)

Here you can use another filename with location like
wb.save('C:\another_filename.xlsx')

Excel will automatically save this file 'another_filename.xlsx' in C folder.
I think it will work for you.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not that simple. As the comment says this part of the code which has wb.save only affects the new temporary worksheet created by Pandas. And not the entire workbook. Even if you comment out this entire section of the scrip it would still overwrite the original .xlsx. Somehow it saves most changes without using the .save method.