# Combining excel spreadsheets using dictionaries

Tags: python, excel, dictionary

I've made a simple example where I am trying to merge two spreadsheets. The aim is to create a spreadsheet with 'Name of City', 'State' and 'Population' as the three columns. I think the way to do it is to use dictionaries.

I've had a go at it myself and this is what I have so far.

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qFbIC.png)
[data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xewwb.png)

Comment: Please include your code and data as text in your question, not as images.

Comment: easiest way would be to use `pandas.read_excel` to get a 2 `DafaFrames` and then merge these

Answer (score 3):

Do you know the pandas package?

You can read data from an excel file to a `DataFrame` with `pandas.read_excel` and then merge the two dataframes on the `Name of City` column.

Here's a short example that shows how easy merging two dataframes is using pandas:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd
In [3]: df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Name of City': ['Sydney', 'Melbourne'],
   ...:                     'State': ['NSW', 'VIC']})    
In [4]: df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Name of City': ['Sydney', 'Melbourne'],
   ...:                     'Population': [1000000, 200000]})
In [5]: result = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='Name of City')
In [6]: result
Out[6]:
  Name of City State  Population
0       Sydney   NSW     1000000
1    Melbourne   VIC      200000
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this?

```
import os
import os.path
import xlrd
import xlsxwriter

file_name = input("Decide the destination file name in DOUBLE QUOTES: ")
merged_file_name = file_name + ".xlsx"
dest_book = xlsxwriter.Workbook(merged_file_name)
dest_sheet_1 = dest_book.add_worksheet()
dest_row = 1
temp = 0
path = input("Enter the path in DOUBLE QUOTES: ")
for root,dirs,files in os.walk(path):
    files = [ _ for _ in files if _.endswith('.xlsx') ]
    for xlsfile in files:
        print ("File in mentioned folder is: " + xlsfile)
        temp_book = xlrd.open_workbook(os.path.join(root,xlsfile))
        temp_sheet = temp_book.sheet_by_index(0)
        if temp == 0:
            for col_index in range(temp_sheet.ncols):
                str = temp_sheet.cell_value(0, col_index)
                dest_sheet_1.write(0, col_index, str)
            temp = temp + 1
        for row_index in range(1, temp_sheet.nrows):
            for col_index in range(temp_sheet.ncols):
                str = temp_sheet.cell_value(row_index, col_index)
                dest_sheet_1.write(dest_row, col_index, str)
            dest_row = dest_row + 1
dest_book.close()
book = xlrd.open_workbook(merged_file_name)
sheet = book.sheet_by_index(0)
print "number of rows in destination file are: ", sheet.nrows
print "number of columns in destination file are: ", sheet.ncols
```

It seems like this should work just as well.

```
import pandas as pd

# filenames
excel_names = ["xlsx1.xlsx", "xlsx2.xlsx", "xlsx3.xlsx"]

# read them in
excels = [pd.ExcelFile(name) for name in excel_names]

# turn them into dataframes
frames = [x.parse(x.sheet_names[0], header=None,index_col=None) for x in excels]

# delete the first row for all frames except the first
# i.e. remove the header row -- assumes it's the first
frames[1:] = [df[1:] for df in frames[1:]]

# concatenate them..
combined = pd.concat(frames)

# write it out
combined.to_excel("c.xlsx", header=False, index=False)
```

[How to concatenate three excels files xlsx using python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15793349/how-to-concatenate-three-excels-files-xlsx-using-python)