# Merging two excel files using python with mismatching sizes

Tags: python, excel, pandas, xlwt

I have been trying to merge those two excel files.
Those files are already ready to be joined just as you can see in my image example.
I have tried the solutions from the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15793349/how-to-concatenate-three-excels-files-xlsx-using-python) using pandas and xlwt, but I still can not save both in one file.

[image]

[image]

Desired result is:

[image]

P.s: the two data frames may have mismatch columns and rows which should just be ignored. I am looking for a way to paste one in another using panda.

how can I approach this problem? Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 3):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_excel('main.xlsx')
df.index = np.arange(1, len(df) + 1)
df1 = pd.read_excel('alt.xlsx', header=None, names=list(df))

for i in list(df):
    if any(pd.isnull(df[i])):
        df[i] = df1[i]

print(df)
df.to_excel("<filename>.xlsx", index=False)
```

Try this. The main.xlsx is your first excel file while the alt.xlsx is the second one.

Comment: And to write it back to an Excel-file, you can then add: df.to_excel("<filename>.xlsx", index=False)

Comment: there thousands of lines, this is just a mall example. I can not track all the lines like this. I just want to join, merge them.

Comment: You can replace those lines with a loop. I have edited the code

Comment: Without an actual example of such an Excel file it is really difficult to come up with a solution. If they are mismatched you will have to write more conditional statements to deal with them. Without an actual example it is not possible to come up with a more specific solution.