# How to read multiple excel files and load into one excel sheet

Tags: python, xlsx

I have multiple excel files in one directory 
Directory :

```
H:\Learning\files
```

Files :

```
customer-status.xlsx
sales-feb-2014.xlsx
sales-jan-2014.xlsx
sales-mar-2014.xlsx
sample-salesv3.xlsx
```

I'm trying to load `sales.xlsx` files into one master `sales` file.
here is my script :

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import glob


all_data = pd.DataFrame()
for f in glob.glob('H:Learning/sales*.xlsx'):
    df = pd.read_excel(f)
    all_data = all_data.append(df, ignore_index=True)
print(all_data)
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('mastersales.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
all_data.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')
writer.save()
```

when i'm trying to print `sales*.xlsx` files and it's showing empty Data frames

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: []
```

More over I have implemented this code from this SO answered question

[How to concatenate three excels files xlsx using python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15793349/how-to-concatenate-three-excels-files-xlsx-using-python)
but this is not giving me required result

Comment: try `for f in glob.glob('H:/Learning/*.xlsx'):`

Comment: I have tried like that but it is not traversing into files folder where sales xlsx files are there

Comment: Does `print(glob.glob('H:Learning/*.xlsx'))` show your expected files ? If not, you might not be in the right folder. The rest of the code looks good..

Comment: It looks like your print function is outside for loop

Comment: print funciton outside the loop is no problem, the loop should save all the required data in `all_data`

Comment: I don't know if it's a typo, but notice that in the line  `for f in glob.glob('H:Learning/sales*.xlsx')` the address don't match the directory, try `print(df)` inside the for loop and see if it prints anything

Comment: By reading your question a second time, it seems you are not looking at the right directory since your files are in `H:\Learning\files`. Replace the `for` lop by the right path: `for f in glob.glob('H:Learning/files/*.xlsx'):`.

Comment: @AlexandreB. this is I have given :  for f in glob.glob(r'H:\Learning\files*.xlsx'):

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this path in the `for` loop:

```
glob.glob(r'H:\Learning\files\sales*.xlsx')
```

Comment: for f in glob.glob(r'H:\Learning\files\sales*.xlsx'):

Answer (score 1):

The path is not correct. Use :

```
glob.glob(r'H:\Learning\sales*.xlsx')
```

Comment: If you have folders inside "Learning" please add them to the path and then try. The code I have shared is worked in my Windows Machine

Comment: I have added full path and it is working and I have gave 10 from my side