# Moving sheets from excel files into one workbook using openpyxl

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl

So I've been trying to code a script which loads all excel files from a specific location and moves worksheets inside these files into one workbook. I'm ending with and error:

`AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'DataFrame'`.

I'm pretty new to this so I would really appreciate any tip on how to make that work. I can stick only 
with openpyxl because at the moment I cannot install xlrd module on my workstation.

```
from pandas import ExcelWriter
import glob
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl

writer = ExcelWriter("output.xlsx")
for filename in glob.glob (r"C:\path\*.xlsx"):
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename)
    for ws in wb.sheetnames:
        ws = wb[ws]
        print (ws)
        data = ws.values
        columns = next(data)[0:]
        df= pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)
        print(df)
        for df in df.DataFrame:
            df.to_excel([writer,sheet_name= ws)

writer.save()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to concatenate three excels files xlsx using python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15793349/how-to-concatenate-three-excels-files-xlsx-using-python)

Comment: It didn't help me out with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first you have to use sheet_name as a string not an object and another thing is last for loop is not needed as we loop through sheet names.

```
from pandas import ExcelWriter
import glob
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl


writer = ExcelWriter("output.xlsx")
for filename in glob.glob (r"C:\path\*.xlsx"):
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename)
    for ws in wb.sheetnames:
        ws1 = wb[ws]
        data = ws1.values
        columns = next(data)[0:]
        df= pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)
        df.to_excel(writer,sheet_name=ws,index = False)

writer.save()
```

Comment: it gives me an error:
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:/path/test.py", line 16, in <module>
>  columns = next(data)[0:]
> StopIteration

Comment: also make sure use ws1 in data = ws.values

Comment: Location is okay,  I see frames being loaded and I changed ws to ws1.

Comment: unfortunately yes.

Comment: I have tried it on the different workstation, it works.Thanks for help

Comment: Cool glad to hear