# how to combine multiple excel file and loop them (PYTHON)

Tags: python, excel, loops

I have 20 excels file which name is

'apple1.xlsx'
'apple2.xlsx'
'apple3.xlsx'
.
.
.
'orange1.xlsx'
'orange2.xlsx'
'orange3.xlsx'

I dont know **how to loop the data to combine every excel file into 1 file** and I also want to have index name in final excel file (which is apple1, apple2, apple3, ...,orange1, orange2, orange3)

Help me please.
thank you so much everyone

Comment: I might be able to come up with an answer, just let me know these things
1. how many sheets are present in each xlsx file ?
2. are all sheets named the same ?
3. what is the nature of the data in each xlsx file?
4. Show me what ever code you have done so far.

Comment: Also refer to the answer here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15793349/how-to-concatenate-three-excels-files-xlsx-using-python

Comment: 1. only 1 sheet per file

Comment: 2. every sheet and excel files are the same. 3. data in each file , some columns are text and some columns are float

Comment: please refer the link i have shared above

Comment: i have tried this city = ["Apple", "Banana", "Orange"]
dfs = []
for city in cities :
    for x in range(1,26) :
        dfs = [pd.read_excel(str(city)+str(x)+'.xlsx' for city in cities]
        dfs = pd.concat(dfs, keys=stocks, names=['Apple1', 'Apple2',...,'Orange1','Orange2','Orange3'])  #to get new index column name

Comment: Does it work?, what output do you get ?

Comment: Try the other method also, xlrd and xlwt ... which is mentioned in another answer at the same above mentioned link

Comment: got one problem is i can't add index name. after combine all excel file i still want to have new column as an index name for me . (need each excel file's name to be and index name)

Comment: By index name you mean column name in the combined xl ?

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with a library pandas

step 1: install pandas

```
pip install pandas
```

step2: put all your files you want to merge into a folder . and get its path in my case path is `"E:\test\\"` you should replace with yours

step 3:
run the below code to get your merged excel file

```
import glob
import pandas as pd
path=r"E:\test\\" #replace with your path
files = glob.glob(path+ "/*.xlsx") #getting all the file path
merged = pd.concat(map(pd.read_excel,files),axis=1) #reading and combining them into one file
merged.to_excel("merged.xlsx") #saving the result
```

step 4 (optional): customization,

There are several way you can merge those file, please refer pandas documentation.
for example `axis=1` refers append by column, `axis=0` refers append by row (while appending by rows you may need to set `ignore_index=True`)