# How to enter values to an .xlsx file and keep formatting of cells

Tags: python, excel, formatting, xlwt, xlutils

I have a results analysing spreadsheet where i need to enter my raw data into a 8x6 cell 'plate' which has formatted cells to produce the output based on a graph created. This .xlsx file is heavily formatted with formulas for the analysis, and it is a commercial spreadsheet so I cannot replicate these formulas.

I am using python 2.7 to obtain the raw results into a list and I have tried using xlwt and xlutils to copy the spreadsheet to enter the results. When I do this it loses all formatting when I save the file. I am wondering whether there is a different way in which I can make a copy of the spreadsheet to enter my results.

Also when I have used xlutils.copy I can only save the file as a .xls file, not an xlsx, is this the reason why it loses formatting?

Comment: These answers kinda suck, and honestly it's really sad that 2 years in we still don't have a way to paste values-only text to Excel using python. MATLAB has had this for YEARS! and it's a one-liner, too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First:

Apparently xlwt, does not support xlsx.
[does xlwt support xlsx Format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15738904/does-xlwt-support-xlsx-format)

Other library to use with format:

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/XlsxWriter

or

http://pythonexcels.com/python-excel-mini-cookbook/

Comment: No xlsxwriter does not support preserving the formating

Answer (score 0):

While Destrif is correct, `xlutils` uses `xlwt` which doesn't support the `.xlsx` file format.

However, you will also find that `xlsxwritter` is unable to write `xlrd` formatted objects.

Similarly, the `python-excel-cookbook` he recommends only works if you are running Windows and have excel installed. A better alternative for this would be `xlwings` as it works for Windows and Mac with Excel installed.

If you are looking for something more platform agnostic, you could try writing your `xlsx` file using `openpyxl`.